# Any reason not to exec in shell script?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of wrapper shell scripts which manipulate command line arguments and do some stuff before invoking another binary at the end. Is there any reason to not always `exec` the binary at the end? It seems like this would be simpler and more efficient, but I never see it done.

Comment: It depends, do you want to continue using the shell or not? If not, then go ahead and use `exec`, but if you want to continue using the shell once the program/script ended you can't use `exec`. If you read e.g. [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) you will see that the `exec` command "...replaces the shell".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check `/usr/bin`, you will likely find many many shell scripts that end with an `exec` command.  Just as an example, here is `/usr/bin/ps2pdf` (debian):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Convert PostScript to PDF.

# Currently, we produce PDF 1.4 by default, but this is not guaranteed
# not to change in the future.
version=14

ps2pdf="`dirname \"$0\"`/ps2pdf$version"
if test ! -x "$ps2pdf"; then
____ps2pdf="ps2pdf$version"
fi
exec "$ps2pdf" "$@"
```

`exec` is used because it eliminates the need for keeping the shell process active after it is no longer needed.

My `/usr/bin` directory has over 150 shell scripts that use `exec`.  So, the use of `exec` is common.

A reason not to use `exec` would be if there was some processing to be done *after* the binary finished executing.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with your assessment that this is not a common practice. That said, it's not *always* the right thing.

The most common scenario where I end a script with the execution of another command, but can't reasonably use `exec`, is if I need a cleanup hook to be run *after* the command at the end finishes. For instance:

```
#!/bin/sh

# create a temporary directory
tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d myprog.XXXXXX)
cleanup() { rm -rf "$tempdir"; }
trap cleanup 0

# use that temporary directory for our program
exec myprog --workdir="$tempdir" "$@"
```

...won't actually clean up `tempdir` after execution! Changing that `exec myprog` to merely `myprog` has some disadvantages -- continued memory usage from the shell, an extra process-table entry, signals being potentially delivered to the shell rather than to the program that it's executing -- but it also ensures that the shell is still around on `myprog`'s exit to run any traps required.